# How to make citations using sentence fragments instead of numbers?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, endnotes, bibentry, custom-bib

Does anyone know a way to make endnote citations that use words or sentence fragments from the body of the text, instead of numbers or symbols? (My reason for doing this is so that there is no citation clutter in the body of the text, but that interested readers can look to the back and easily find the reference for a certain fact.) For example, the sentence

*He stated that he wished to know the land.*

would be cited in the endnotes as

*"he wished to know the land." Heisenberg, 1949, p. 32.*

I am trying to do this with bibTex. The endnote citations would be followed by the full, bibTexed bibliography. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Don't do this. If you really must, at least use footnotes so your readers don't have to search through pages and then try to figure out where in the list of notes, this bit of text is. But it would still be horrible. How will your reader know when you have cited something and when not? Unless you are going to change your text to always make this obvious, you leave your reader to guess when you might have cited a source and when not.

Comment: I think this is more like [indexing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Indexing)

Comment: @cfr -- this is a fairly common style in many serious nonfiction books, and it isn't really a problem, unless one insists on referring to every note as it occurs.  (in the books i've read that use this style, *really* important "additional" information is usually handled as a traditional, bottom-of-page, footnote.  the endnotes are usually citations, "where i got this information", although occasionally there's some additional material, such as from an interview, that is interesting, but not necessary to the main point in the text.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've also seem books done like this. I find them horrible in terms of actually finding information. Even regular endnotes, which are bad enough, are several orders of magnitude better.

Comment: @cfr -- i guess we just have different reading styles.  when a book really "flows", i don't like to be interrupted by notes, unless it's really "urgent", and if 90+% of the notes are simply citations, it's even more bothersome.  so i read a chapter, which usually ends at a good breaking point, then go to the back and skim the notes; if there's a really illuminating one, i'm not so far along that i've forgotten the context.  for my reading style, this would make a very interesting package.

Comment: @zadram -- my comments so far haven't been very helpful for you.  i don't think there's any clean way to do this with `bibtex`, but maybe with an "anchored" hyperlink and using `\pageref` within the note.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution to my question. Using the 'endnotes' package, we can define a function

```
% define a new citation function
\newcommand{\mycite}[3][]{\let\theendnote\relax\endnotetext{``#2": \citet[#1]{#3}}} % arguments: 1: page (optional); 2: sentence fragment; 3: citation
```

Then it can be used as follows within the text:

```
\mycite[p. 32]{he wished to know the land}{heisenberg1949}
```

and then the citation will show up in the endnotes, without superscripted numbers, as

> "he wished to know the land": Heisenberg (1949, p. 32)

For more complications, such as additional comments in the endnotes or multiple citations, we can define additional functions:

```
\newcommand{\myciteeg}[3][]{\let\theendnote\relax\endnotetext{``#2": E.g., \citet[#1]{#3}}} % the above, with an 'E.g.'
\newcommand{\mycitesee}[3][]{\let\theendnote\relax\endnotetext{``#2": See \citet[#1]{#3}}} % the above, but with a 'See'
\newcommand{\myendnote}[1]{\let\theendnote\relax\endnotetext{#1}} % for general endnotes
\newcommand{\myciteinside}[3][]{{``#2": \citet[#1]{#3}}} % for multiple citations at one go; must use this as the first citation inside \myendnote
\newcommand{\myciteinsideeg}[3][]{{``#2": E.g., \citet[#1]{#3}}} % the above, with an 'E.g.'
\newcommand{\myciteinsidesee}[3][]{{``#2": See \citet[#1]{#3}}} % the above, but with a 'See'
```

and make citations like the following:

```
\myendnote{\myciteinside[pp. 258-259]{Darwin generally...goal}{gould2000}; see also \citet[pp. 242-243]{gould2003}}
```

which yields

> "Darwin generally...goal": Gould (2000, pp. 258-259); see also Gould (2003, pp.
>   242-243)

Comment: Instead of using `"` (double-quote mark) in the instances of `\`\`#2"`, consider using `''` (consecutive *single*-quote marks). Or, load the `csquotes` package and write `\enquote{#2}`. Separately, do use `--` rather than just `-` to denote ranges of numbers, and use `\ldots` instead of typing `...`.